# Update a value by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, linq

I placed a label that named as LabelTotalNumber on Asp.net webform. I want update a value every one minute by jQuery without refresh the form. How do I do it?

I can do this way in Page_Load event for one time.

```
var sqlResult = (From obj in db.RequestList
                 where obj.IsApproved == "Approved"
                 select obj).count();
LabelTotalNumber.text = sqlResult;
```

Comment: If you want the page to update without a postback, you'll need to use ajax and a web service (e.g. jQuery ajax() method and a ASP.NET WCF service)

Comment: Do you know how to use jQuery?

Comment: Do you have any sample code or link that I can learn?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-Microsoft-box you could use an [UpdatePanel and a Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx).

If you don't like the contents of the Microsoft box and wanna use jQuery/javascript you could send AJAX requests at regular intervals (using the [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) method) to an [ASP.NET PageMethod](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) (in which case basically you will have to give yourself a little pain to read jQuery's [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)/[tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and write a little code).

So an ASP.NET PageMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static int Approved()
{
    return (from obj in db.RequestList
            where obj.IsApproved == "Approved"
            select obj).Count();
}
```

and then hammer this PageMethod with an AJAX request every minute or so:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/foo.aspx/Approved',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{ }',
        success: function(result) {
            var count = result.d;
            // TODO: do something with the count returned by the server
            // like assigning it to a label or something:
            $('#someLabelId').html(count);
        }
    });
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery ajax to invoke a server page where you can do the database operation.
Execute your script in a specific interval using setInterval method.

```
var tid = setInterval(UpdateData, 60000);
function UpdateData() {
  $.get("yourserverpage.ashx",function(data){
   $("#yourDiv").html(data)
 });
}
```

Assumung `yourserverpage.ashx` will handle your database updation when it is invoked and yourDiv is the div where you want to show the updated data ( assuming `yourserverpage.ashx` is returning the markup to be displayed.